# Disqus Loading the same comments for dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, disqus

I have a dynamic page that loads different ideas. I am using disqus for the comments, but disqus keeps loading the same comments for each idea.

Here is the website. http://tech-in.org/submitted_ideas/index.php.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
     if( typeof DISQUS != 'undefined' ) { 
      DISQUS.reset({ 
        reload: true, 
         config: function () { 
           this.page.identifier = '<?php echo $title; ?>'; 
           this.page.url = 'http://tech-in.org/submitted_ideas/idea.php?id=<?php echo $idea_id; ?>'; 
         } 
       }); 
    } 
    var disqus_shortname = 'techinorg'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
    var disqus_identifier = '<?php echo $title; ?>';
    var disqus_url = 'http://tech-in.org/submitted_ideas/idea.php?id=<?php echo $idea_id; ?>';
    var disqus_title = document.getElementById('disqus_post_title').innerHTML;
    var disqus_message = document.getElementById('disqus_post_message').innerHTML;


    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

Please kindly help with what is causing the error and what can i do to resolve it

Answer (score 5):

Disqus decides which comments to load based on the `disqus_identifier` you specify.  When a different "idea" is loaded, ensure that you provide a unique `disqus_identifier` that corresponds to that idea.  (It's not clear what `$title` represents in your PHP script, which is what is currently being assigned to `disqus_identifier`.)

Comment: Hello Cheeken, $title is the title for each idea. You will see that the disqus_identifier is different when you the view the source of each idea page. That means that the title is rendered correctly.

Comment: Thanks Madmartigan, setting the disqus_url to be same with disqus_identifier has solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your identifier is not unique enough, see reference documentation here: http://docs.disqus.com/help/14/

It states:

> When Disqus-enabled pages are visited, Disqus uses this identifier to
>   determine the appropriate comment thread to load. If the appropriate
>   thread could not be found, a new thread is created. Disqus identifiers
>   keep threads and pages associated.

Comment: Thank Jakub, i solved the problem by using the URL as the identifier. But my doubt is that each idea has it's own title. Isn't that unique enough for Disqus to use?

Comment: @Stanley, looks like it isn't unique enough, sometimes the more unique the better, besides who cares it is a unique identifier, you could make a hash of it, and it would still work.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same problem on a page that uses AJAX to load new content with a new disqus thread. The solution for me was setting both the identifier and the url equal to the same thing.

```
DISQUS.reset({ 
    reload: true, 
     config: function () { 
       this.page.identifier = 'http://example.com/#!' + myPageID;
       this.page.url = 'http://example.com/#!' + myPageID;
     }});
```

where myPageID is an integer that I dynamically update using AJAX

Comment: Isn't it strange that all the solutions I have found did not work but yours, this is definitely a Disqus issue, but your comment saved me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this working as follows.

The Disqus doco for Ajax sites [1], states the `requirements` are to set both variables `this.page.identifier` and `this.page.URL` using a `full hashbang #!`

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.identifier = window.location.origin + '/#!' + identifier 
    this.page.url = window.location.origin + '/#!' + identifier
}
```

Confusingly, the example `recipe` [2] linked in the above mentioned doco, does not do this.

References:

[1] https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites

[2] https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/snippets/js/disqus-reset/disqus_reset.html

Comment: This caused Google to crawl hundreds of duplicate pages on my site, using hashbang is a bad idea.

Comment: @idan-shechter I agree... and for many other reasons to numerous to mention here I've stopped using it. Note that Disqus doesn't appear to have any real support for non-server based installs. There are many who are not happy with their offering. E.g. https://randocity.com/2017/10/26/why-you-should-not-use-disqus-on-your-site/