# Same disqus thread is loading for all articles

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, disqus

I have SPA pages that uses durandaljs and knockoutjs. Now I am going to implement a support of disqus plugin for my site.

When I added disqus I have found that the same comments is showing up for different pages with different URL (I used durandal for URL rewriting).

I guess that root of this issue is that my rewrote URL's are distinguished by full hashbang(#!)
[image]

The code is following:

```
    var disqus_shortname = 'somename';
    var disqus_identifier = context.id;

    (function () {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();

    if (typeof DISQUS != 'undefined') {
        DISQUS.reset({
            reload: true,
            config: function () {
                this.page.title = "title" + context.id;
                this.page.identifier = context.id;
                this.page.url = "http://localhost:23054/#!ideas/details/" + context.id;
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
```

View:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

I hope somebody uses disqus comments with SPA pages and knows how to help me to solve this.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944287/disqus-loading-the-same-comments-for-dynamic-pages?rq=1 to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's my solution:

```
    var id = context.id;
    disqus_shortname = 'somename',
    disqus_identifier = id,
    disqus_title = id,
    disqus_url = "http://someurl.com/#!" + id;
        if ($('head script[src="http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js"]').length == 0) {
            (function () {
                var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
            })();
        }
        if (typeof DISQUS != "undefined") {
            DISQUS.reset({
                reload: true,
                config: function () {
                    this.page.identifier = id;
                    this.page.url = "http://someurl.com/#!" + id;
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that your identifier isn't unique enough. From the Disqus documentation:

> When Disqus-enabled pages are visited, Disqus uses this identifier to
>   determine the appropriate comment thread to load. If the appropriate
>   thread could not be found, a new thread is created.

I'm not sure what `context.id` is, but make sure that this is unique for each thread and unique enough for Disqus' purposes.